# Filter specific lines from a plain text file with PHP

Tags: php, regex

Hi I'm having a problem with filtering certain lines out of a text file. When I run a program a plain text file is generated listing error messages related to validating a file. However I need to ignore some of the errors generated, mainly ones with imported or not found in search path in the error description like the ones below:

```
static-state.y:8: error: module "inet-types" not found in search path
mpls-static-state.y:11: error: module "y-types" not found in search path
mpls-static-state.y:11: warning: imported module y-types not used
mpls-static-state.y:15: error: module "context-state" not found in search path
mpls-static-state.y:15: warning: imported module context-state not used
mpls-static-state.y:19: error: module "contexts" not found in search path
```

There will be other error messages that I will need so I can't empty the file completely, also I'm reading the text file and displaying these errors on a webpage. I read from the file like this:

```
if(file_exists("stderr.txt")){
    $fh = fopen("stderr.txt", 'r');
    $errorOutput = fread($fh, 25000);
}
```

Then I use the $errorOutput to store what is in the text file. What would be the best way to filter the error lines I don't want out? Was trying to create a regex but not having any luck getting it working can anyone help?

Comment: Command line yes or no? Platform? Selection criteria? On a linux box, I would just use _grep_.

Comment: Hi this is running on windows, the text file is generated from running a bash script. PHP is used to read the text file from the location that it's generated in. I need to remove the error messages I don't need from the text file using PHP while keeping the ones I do need.

Comment: You could use anchors(`^$`), with the `m` modifier and that will break the search per line. Then just use `preg_replace` with a regex that matches the lines you dont want.. Alternatively `grep` with the `v` flag ignores found matches..

Comment: So just run `$errorOutput2 = preg_replace('/^.*? not found in search path\s*$/m', '', $errorOutput);`?

Comment: @syck should work, no?

Comment: Thanks syck and chris that was just what I needed got it working there!

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with ***anchors*** and ***lookaheads***:

```
^(?:.(?!(?:not found)))+$
# ^  - match the beginning of the line
# (?:.) - match any character except a newline
# (?! - negative lookahead
# $ - end of the line
```

See <kbd>[a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hA8gG6/1)</kbd> (mind the `multiline` modifier!).